# LSTM Weight Matrix Interpretation

Tags: neural-network, keras, rnn, theano

Consider the following code in Keras for building a LSTM model.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(30, input_dim=22,return_sequences=True, init = 'glorot_uniform'))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Nadam')

    model.fit(train3d, trainY3d, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=8)
```

As one can see there is only 1 LSTM layer. I see there are 14 matrices as output. If you check this [link](http://euler.stat.yale.edu/~tba3/stat665/lectures/lec21/notebook21.html) you would notice that there are 4 triples (Input gate, Forget gate, Cell State, Output gate) of W, U (parameter matrices) and b (bias vector) each for the LSTM layer. And then there are 2 matrices W and b for the dense layer.

My question is let's say for this case of 1 layer LSTM, is there a way to attribute 100% of Y to the impact for each input feature $X_i \forall i$.

Comment: can you elaborate this - "is there a way to attribute 100% of Y to the impact for each input feature"